# Error installing php-snmp in CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, php, snmp, cacti

I'm currently on php 5.6 on CentOS 6.7.

I'm trying to install

**yum install php-snmp**

I keep getting

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * extras: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * updates: mirrors.seas.harvard.edu
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-snmp.x86_64 0:5.3.3-47.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6 for package: php-snmp-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-47.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php56w-common-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-mbstring-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-opcache-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-fpm-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-pdo-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-cli-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-xml-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-fpm.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-fpm.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-opcache.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-opcache.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-pgsql-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
---> Package php56w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-pgsql.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-pgsql.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
--> Processing Conflict: php56w-common-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.6
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

---

How do I avoid that ?

---

## Updated

@symcbean : Thanks for your suggestions. I've tried

**yum install php56w-snmp -y**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * extras: mirror.stjschools.org
 * updates: mirrors.seas.harvard.edu
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-snmp.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.23-1.w6 for package: php56w-snmp-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-mbstring-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-opcache-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-fpm-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-pdo-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-cli-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-xml-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
---> Package php56w-common.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-fpm.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-fpm.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-opcache.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-opcache.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php56w-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.22-1.w6 for package: php56w-pgsql-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64
---> Package php56w-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
---> Package php56w-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-pgsql.x86_64 0:5.6.22-1.w6 will be updated
---> Package php56w-pgsql.x86_64 0:5.6.23-1.w6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                         Arch                                   Version                                     Repository                                Size
===================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php56w-snmp                                     x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                  32 k
Updating for dependencies:
 php56w                                          x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                 2.7 M
 php56w-cli                                      x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                 2.6 M
 php56w-common                                   x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                 1.2 M
 php56w-fpm                                      x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                 1.3 M
 php56w-mbstring                                 x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                 944 k
 php56w-opcache                                  x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                 100 k
 php56w-pdo                                      x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                  94 k
 php56w-pgsql                                    x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                  95 k
 php56w-xml                                      x86_64                                 5.6.23-1.w6                                 webtatic                                 148 k

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)
Upgrade       9 Package(s)

Total download size: 9.2 M
Downloading Packages:
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-cli-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-cli-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-cli-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-common-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-common-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-common-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-fpm-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-fpm-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-fpm-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-mbstring-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-mbstring-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-mbstring-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-opcache-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-opcache-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-opcache-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-pdo-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-pdo-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-pdo-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-pgsql-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-pgsql-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-pgsql-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-snmp-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-snmp-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-snmp-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://us-east.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-xml-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-xml-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
https://sp.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/x86_64/php56w-xml-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.


Error Downloading Packages:
  php56w-common-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-common-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php56w-mbstring-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-mbstring-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php56w-snmp-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-snmp-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php56w-xml-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-xml-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php56w-pgsql-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-pgsql-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php56w-cli-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-cli-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php56w-fpm-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-fpm-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php56w-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php56w-pdo-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-pdo-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  php56w-opcache-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64: failure: php56w-opcache-5.6.23-1.w6.x86_64.rpm from webtatic: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a non-standard PHP install on your system - either back it out and replace with the CENTOS distribution then install the php-snmp rpm or keep your existing PHP and `yum install php56w-snmp` (note the 'w')

Comment: I'll stick with your second suggestion. keep my existing PHP and `yum install php56w-snmp`

Comment: After running that, I got a bunch of `Trying other mirror.` , how do I know if I installed `php56w-snmp` correctly ?

Comment: `rpm -q -l php56w-snmp` but read *all* the output of your attempt to install carefully. To get the other php56w packages installed you must have been using a non-standard repository before. See also https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/